# Ant Script build for Web and App Deployment

Tags: java, ant, weblogic

i am developing a dynamic web project.
and i having problem when i want to build it using ant script.
my purpose is to adopt three-tier concept, which is have business-layer and presentation-layer in different machine.
i use weblogic server as web server (presentation layer) and app server (business layer)

here is my build.xml :

```
<property name="build" value="./build" />
<property name="dist" value="./dist" />
<!-- <property name="conf" value="./config" /> -->
<property name="src" value="./src" />
<property name="web" value="./WebContent" />
<property name="lib" value="${web}/WEB-INF/lib" />
<property name="webinf" value="${web}/WEB-INF" />
<property name="metainf" value="${web}/META-INF" />
<property name="servletLib" value="C:\Oracle\MiddlewareOneBC\wlserver_12.1\server\lib" />
<property name="deploydir" value="C:\Oracle\MiddlewareOneBC\user_projects\domains\OneBCDomain\autodeploy" />
<property name="project.name" value="OneBCApplication" />

<path id="build.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${servletLib}" includes="**/*.jar" />
</path>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build}" />
    <delete dir="${dist}" />
</target>

<target name="init">
    <tstamp />
    <mkdir dir="${build}" />
    <mkdir dir="${build}/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist}" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}/classes" optimize="on" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="build.classpath" />
    </javac>
    <copy todir="${build}/classes">
        <fileset dir="${src}" excludes="ddl/*" />
        <fileset dir="${src}" excludes="dml/*" />
        <fileset dir="${src}" excludes="**/*.xls" />
        <fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.xml" />
        <fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.properties" />
        <!-- <fileset dir="${conf}" includes="**/*" /> -->
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="war" depends="compile">
    <war destfile="${dist}/${project.name}.war" webxml="${webinf}/web.xml">
        <lib dir="${lib}" />
        <classes dir="${build}/classes"/>
        <fileset dir="${web}">
            <include name="**/*.*" />
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/lib/*" />
        </fileset>
    </war>
</target>

<target name="ear" depends="war">
    <ear destfile="${dist}/${project.name}EAR.ear" appxml="${metainf}/application.xml">
        <fileset dir="${dist}" includes="*.war" />
    </ear>
</target>

<target name="warweb" depends="compile">
    <war destfile="${dist}/web/${project.name}Web.war" webxml="${webinf}/web.xml">
        <lib dir="${lib}" excludes="**/BV_*.*" />
        <classes dir="${build}/classes">
            <!-- <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.class"/> -->
            <exclude name="com/**"/>
        </classes>

        <fileset dir="${web}">
            <include name="**/*.*" />
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/lib/*" />
        </fileset>
    </war>
     <jar destfile="${dist}/lib/${project.name}.jar" basedir="${build}/classes"/>
</target>

<target name="earweb" depends="warweb">
    <ear destfile="${dist}/${project.name}Static.ear" appxml="${metainf}/application.xml">
        <fileset dir="${dist}/web" includes="*.war" />
    </ear>
</target>

    <target name="earapp" depends="warweb">
    <ear destfile="${dist}/${project.name}App.ear" appxml="${metainf}/application.xml">
        <fileset dir="${dist}/web" includes="*.war" />
        <zipfileset dir="${dist}/lib" includes="*.jar" prefix="APP-INF/lib" />
        <zipfileset dir="${lib}" includes="**/BV_*.*" prefix="APP-INF/lib" />           
    </ear>
</target>



<target name="deploywar" depends="ear">
    <copy todir="${deploydir}">
        <fileset dir="${dist}" includes="*.war" />
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="deployear" depends="ear">
    <copy todir="${deploydir}">
        <fileset dir="${dist}" includes="*.ear" />
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="undeploy">
    <delete file="${deploydir}/${project.name}EAR.ear"/>
    <delete file="${deploydir}/${project.name}EAR.war"/>
</target>
```

how to build it separately ? and how the request from presentation layer can comunicate with business layer? is there any configuration in weblogic that has to be done to made these two layer communicate?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is really confusing. You can do something like build 2 war files and deploy each one to a different managed server in Weblogic. But it's hard to tell what you're asking. Are you having an error somewhere?

Comment: ANT is primarily a build tool. By all means, use it to build the artifacts (JAR or WAR or EAR files) associated with each tier, but I recommend investigating a proper mechanism for managing deployments. After all you'll need to setup dynamic information such as the hostnames/IP addresses and credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Using fileset task you specify what jar file you want to include for app server or web server.

```
    <ear destfile="${build.dir}/myapp.ear" appxml="${src.dir}/metadata/application.xml">
     <fileset dir="${build.dir}" includes="*.jar,*.war"/>
    </ear>
```

just you two ear task to create two ear one for app server and one for web server.